# Extracting media duration in R

Tags: r, ffmpeg, data.table

I'm investigating the fastest way to extract film duration in R using `ffprobe` and the `data.table` package.

## Setup Example Source Media

```sh
wget https://ia801403.us.archive.org/13/items/AboutBan1935/AboutBan1935_512kb.mp4
mv AboutBan1935_512kb.mp4 one.mp4
for file in two.mp4 three.mp4 four.mp4 five.mp4 ; do cp one.mp4 "$file" ; done
```

## Various Approaches

```r
library(data.table)
library(parallel)

# Get locations
executables <- Sys.which(c('ffprobe', 'ffmpeg'))

# Duration Function
get_duration_parallel <- function(files){
  mclapply(X = files, FUN = function(file){
    ffprobe_duration <- paste(executables['ffprobe'],
                              " -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries format=duration ",
                              '"', file, '"', sep = "")

    file_duration <- as.numeric(system(command = ffprobe_duration, intern = TRUE))
    return(file_duration)
  }, mc.cores = detectCores())
}

get_duration <- function(files){
  sapply(X = files, FUN = function(file){
    ffprobe_duration <- paste(executables['ffprobe'],
                              " -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries format=duration ",
                              '"', file, '"', sep = "")

    file_duration <- as.numeric(system(command = ffprobe_duration, intern = TRUE))
    return(file_duration)
  })
}

# Example table
dt <- data.table(Path = list.files(path = ".", pattern = "*.mp4$"))


system.time(
  dt[, Seconds := get_duration_parallel(Path)]
)
# 9.667 seconds    

system.time(
  dt[, Seconds := get_duration(Path)]
)
# 0.078 seconds
```

Am I missing any obvious speed-ups?  Scanning a 500-file archive for ffprobe stats takes ~5 minutes in testing.

Comment: What is the timing of atomic operation? parallelization adds overhead so it is worth only for time consuming processes, if you are using data.table well it is quite difficult to have any really time consuming processes. Anyway your code doesn't seems to use data.table much (just a `:=` on 500 rows table), as the major part of processing is outsourced from R using `system` function. Start with identifying bottleneck.

Comment: I'd do the duration extraction outside of R using GNU `parallel`. Something like: `ls *mp4 | parallel -j 4  "echo -n '{},' ;ffprobe -v quiet -print_format compact=print_section=0:nokey=1:escape=csv -show_entries format=duration {}"` will generate a CSV file with `filename,duration` format. Adjust `j` based on # of simultaneous jobs, realizing that you'll be I/O bound for this operation. GNU `parallel` doesn't need to spin up R cores unlike `mclapply` so it'll definitely be faster and just make it part of your data pipeline. I tried `parallel` on a network folder of 40 mp4s and it took 16s.

Comment: I tried it on a local directory of 100 copies of your sample file and it took 5 user seconds (comment length exceeded in previous comment)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm pretty happy with the `parallel` approach you suggested.